# Input Boxes Help JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

**MAJOR EDIT:** 
Okay, so I am have to create a HTML page like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szBLy.png). I have already done the HTML work but I need help in the Javascript section. SO there are 2 parts of this - first to create additional textboxes when + is clicked, which I have already done

```js
textBoxNum = 2

function addElement() {
 if (textBoxNum => 2)  {
  textBoxNum++;
  var objNewDiv = document.createElement('P');
  objNewDiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder = "Option ' + textBoxNum + '" id = "option' + textBoxNum + '" />';
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(objNewDiv);
 };
;}
```

The second part is to get information from the input boxes and save them into local storage in a variable, how do i do that considering the user could have clicked + and add more input boxes

Comment: You should use an array.

Comment: It technically need not know the new ones only per se, as you simply want to collect all event options in an array and send it some where? so On create, it has to find all the text boxes that has data in them push them into an array and send it somewhere I assume

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't set the Name of variable in that way, instead you can
1) create an array options = [], and keep use options[x]
2) create inputs with certain class (for example class="option") and use
`var options = document.getElementsByClassName("option");`
which returns an array
3) create inputs with certain name(for example name="option") and use
`var options = document.getElementsByName("option");`
which returns an array
4) get an array of all inputs on the page
`var options = document.getElementsByTagName('input');`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response can you revisit my question and help answer it since I have made it much more clear. Thank youl.